# cierre de sesion con tiempo

Tags: session

Buenos dias espero me puedan ayudar y guiar, e estado haciendo un sistema de sesiones, ya logre hacer la mayoria de las cosas, pero ahora quiero cerrar sesion pasando un determinado tiempo, de igual forma detectar cuando el navegador se haya cerrado, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora en mi apartado de logout.php

TEngo echo esto hasta ahora en mi logout.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$mysql=conectarse();
session_start();
$nombreUsuario=$_SESSION['nombre_usuario'];//obtiene nombre del que inicia la sesion

$id_session=session_id();//obtiene id de la conexion
//var_dump($id_session);
session_regenerate_id();
$time_login="SELECT time_login FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$nombreUsuario'";
//$result3=$mysql->query($time_login);
//var_dump($result3);
if(isset($_POST['salir']))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_city');
    $ultimaCont=date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    //var_dump($ultimaCont);
    try
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////Estado del usuario//////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $logout="UPDATE usuarios SET estado='desconectado', time_logout='$ultimaCont' where usuario='$nombreUsuario'";
        $result=$mysql->query($logout);
        //var_dump($result);
        //////////////////////////////Actualiza la sesion/////////////////////////////////
        $sql="UPDATE conexioness SET time_logout='$ultimaCont' where idSession='$id_session'";
        $result2=$mysql->query($sql);

        ///////////////////Destruccion de la sesion//////
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();

       // session_regenerate_id();//Genera un id nuevo por cada sesion

        
       header("Location: ../index.php");
        exit();

    }
    catch(Exeption $e)
    {
        print 'ERROR'.$e->getMessage();
    }


}
else
{
    $fechaGuardada=$_SESSION["ultimoAcceso"];
    var_dump($fechaguardada);
    $tiempoTranscurrido=(strtotime($ultimaCont)-strtotime($fechaGuardada));
    var_dump($tiempoTranscurrido);
    if($tiempoTranscurrido >=60)
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION["ultimoAcceso"]=$ultimaCont;
    }
}




?>
```

---

TEngo echo esto hasta ahora en mi logout.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$mysql=conectarse();
session_start();
$nombreUsuario=$_SESSION['nombre_usuario'];//obtiene nombre del que inicia la sesion

$id_session=session_id();//obtiene id de la conexion
//var_dump($id_session);
session_regenerate_id();
$time_login="SELECT time_login FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$nombreUsuario'";
//$result3=$mysql->query($time_login);
//var_dump($result3);
if(isset($_POST['salir']))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_city');
    $ultimaCont=date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
    //var_dump($ultimaCont);
    try
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////Estado del usuario//////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $logout="UPDATE usuarios SET estado='desconectado', time_logout='$ultimaCont' where usuario='$nombreUsuario'";
        $result=$mysql->query($logout);
        //var_dump($result);
        //////////////////////////////Actualiza la sesion/////////////////////////////////
        $sql="UPDATE conexioness SET time_logout='$ultimaCont' where idSession='$id_session'";
        $result2=$mysql->query($sql);

        ///////////////////Destruccion de la sesion//////
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();

       // session_regenerate_id();//Genera un id nuevo por cada sesion

        
       header("Location: ../index.php");
        exit();

    }
    catch(Exeption $e)
    {
        print 'ERROR'.$e->getMessage();
    }


}
else
{
    $fechaGuardada=$_SESSION["ultimoAcceso"];
    var_dump($fechaguardada);
    $tiempoTranscurrido=(strtotime($ultimaCont)-strtotime($fechaGuardada));
    var_dump($tiempoTranscurrido);
    if($tiempoTranscurrido >=60)
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION["ultimoAcceso"]=$ultimaCont;
    }
}




?>
```

Comment: Podrías subir parte del código como capturas la sesión, y que es lo que has intentado.

Comment: mi sistema de sesion lo manejo basicamente guardando en la bd desde que el usuario se loguea, y en otro campo atravez de ajax, actualizo constantemente; mientras en el usuario esta en nuestra pagina, asi mismo se esta comparando constantemen la fecha de ingreso con el tiempo actual, por ej si ha pasado mas de 10 minutos,  entonces ejecuto mi function de cierre de sesion. siempre comparando el campo de fecha ingreso, con el campo de fecha que se actualiza constantemente.

Answer (score 0):

de forma personal normalmete al crear las sessions las creo una vez que el usuario hace login, ahi declaro las variables de sesion que utilizare, y para destruir la sesion despues de un periodo definido de tiempo, declaro lo siguiente

```
if ($row['pass'] == $pass) { // el usuario y contraseña coinciden


$_SESSION['usr_login'] = $username;
$_SESSION['str'] = time(); //aqui guardo la hora actual en la variable 'str'
$_SESSION['fns'] = $_SESSION['str'] + (15 * 60); // aqui declaro el tiempo que quiero que este activa la sesion y guardo el resultado en 'fns'

header('Location: ../panel-control.php');//redirecciona a la pagina del usuario}
```

eso es cuando el usuario hace login correctamente, luego para destruir la sesion en alguna pagina X.php, suelo agregar una condicion que compare la hora actual con la hora almacenada en la variable 'fns'

```
 $now = time();// almaceno la hora actual en variable
if($now > $_SESSION['fns']) {//comparo la hora actual con la hora almacenada en 'fns'
session_destroy(); //destruyo la sesion si se cumple la condicion.
//mostrar o redireccionar lo que desees
echo "Tu sesion a expirado,
<a href='login.html'>Inicia Sesion</a>";//mostrando mensaje
header('Location: login.html'); //redireccionando
exit;
}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Si comparas que la fecha actual sea mayor, no estas haciendo un bucle infinito o algo así? es decir, no debería de ser una condición más específica?

Comment: no necesariamente, la hora en la que se inicio la sesion esta contenida en $_SESSION['fns'], quedando un valor fijo en esta variable, por otra parte la variable $now almacena la hora en la que se inicio la pagina.

Comment: Oh ahora entiendo, gracias por la información.